# User-defined function does not function, but line-by-line works

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I am aiming to define a function that essentially copies a row based on the number of selectable values in another table. Each new row will contain combinations of unique selectable values. I ran the following code on one measure, but plan to use a loop for multiple measures after I can successfully define a function. However, the function does not run, but I can chunk the code and it works fine. Thanks in advance!

```
output_template_v2<-output_template_v1
measure <- "A"
col <- "1"

add_selOptions_to_output<-function(output_template_v2, measure, col, attributes){
if (tolower(str_sub(attributes$Attribute,-4, -1)) == "_sel"){
  selOptions<-attributes[attributes$Measure.Name ==measure & attributes$Attribute == col & attributes$Program == "Blue",]
}
if (length(selOptions$Attribute > 0)){
  subcopy<- output_template_v2[output_template_v2$Measure == measure,]
  output_template_v2<-output_template_v2[output_template_v2$Measure != measure,]
  subcopy<-subcopy[rep(1, length(selOptions$Attribute)),]
}
for (i in seq_along(selOptions)){
  subcopy[,col][i]<-selOptions$Attribute[i]
}
output_template_v2 <-rbind(output_template_v2, subcopy)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset? you can simply do it using `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

The function works — but it does not modify its function arguments, because function arguments are *copied* into the function. Instead, the function *returns* the modified table. This already works, but the assignment in the last line of your function is redundant, so remove it:

```
add_selOptions_to_output <- function (output_template_v2, measure, col, attributes) {
  if (tolower(str_sub(attributes$Product.Attribute, -4L, -1L)) == "_sel") {
    selOptions <- attributes[
      attributes$Catalog.Measure.Name == measure &
      attributes$Product.Attribute == col &
      attributes$Program == "Blue", ]
  }
  if (length(selOptions$Attribute.Values > 0)) {
    subcopy <- output_template_v2[output_template_v2$`Measure #` == measure, ]
    output_template_v2 <- output_template_v2[output_template_v2$`Measure #` != measure, ]
    subcopy <- subcopy[rep(1L, length(selOptions$Attribute.Values)), ]
  }
  for (i in seq_along(selOptions)) {
    subcopy[, col][i] <- selOptions$Attribute.Values[i]
  }
  rbind(output_template_v2, subcopy)
}
```

Either way, you’ll need to assign the return value of the function back to the argument with which you’re calling it, e.g.:

```
tmpl = add_selOptions_to_output(tmpl, measure, col, attributes)
```

Comment: Of note, my answer does not attempt to change the function’s implementation to make it more readable, but I believe this can and should be done. For example, the `rep` function call is odd; if I understand its purpose correctly, it could be replaced by `seq_along(selOptions$Attribute.Values)`. And the `for` loop can be removed entirely in favour of a single assignment.

Comment: Thank you! I should have added that the output_template_v2 does not change after I run the function. There should be another subcopy row added to the output_template_v2 dataframe, which I am able to achieve if I run it line-by-line.